# In Javascript, what does the reserved keyword "short" do?

Tags: javascript, keyword, reserved-words

I'm merely trying to find the definition and usage of the key word, short, in JavaScript. I do not care about backwards compatibility and the likes, as to say that I don't want responses as to if, how, and why it may be an up to date syntax. I just want the definition. A Simple example would be best. Thank you.

Comment: It does nothing. It's reserved for (potential) future use but currently it's not in the specs.

Comment: Also, it's not a reserved word any more. It was a long time ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They belong to the so-called *future keywords* by the ECMAScript specification.

> **They have no special functionality at present, but they might at some future time, so they cannot be used as identifiers.**

`short` as a reserved word was part of an old ECMAScript specification:

> The following are reserved as future keywords by older ECMAScript specifications (ECMAScript 1 till 3)
> [...] `short` [...]
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

In ECMAScript 5/6 `short` was removed from the list of reserved words. Nonetheless for compatibility with older browsers not implementing either, you shouldn't use it anyway.

Comment: Hello @connexo, Try this, as this was very well documented, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62437585/13399106, and reopen this as it has been re-edited, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62458540/13399106

Answer (score -1):

My guess they were planning on using it for what its for in Java "Storing a whole number between -32768 to 32767." but then decided there was no need to have that integer type so they removed it in ECMAScript 5/6 standard.[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Comment: The keywords were reserved only because they exist in Java. AFAIK, there weren't any plans (at least at the start) what to do with them.

Comment: @VLAZ why would they wait until ECMA6 to remove it. neither of us have any idea, i was suggesting a reason. ps why is everyone on this site so stuck up.